# How to make PrimeNg VirtualScroller responsive height?

Tags: css, angular, layout, primeng, virtualscroll

I have a primeng VirtualScroller and it has a property scrollHeight that fixes some height. I've tried to set 100% at value but it doesn't accept. Also tried to add style or class to component to set height 100% but does not work aswell. How can I make the height have same height of the browser window?

```
<p-virtualScroller [value]="lazyCars" scrollHeight="40em" [itemSize]="150" [rows]="50" [cache]="false"
                   [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadCarsLazy($event)" [totalRecords]="totalLazyCarsLength">
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item" let-i="index">
    <div class="ui-g car-item mt-1">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12" style="font-size: 11px; text-align: center; padding-top: 18px">{{ generateDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</div>
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12" style="font-size: 24px; text-align: center; padding-top: 18px">{{ generateDate() | date: 'HH:mm:ss' }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" style="display: flex">
        <img class="rounded-image" src="../../assets/images/profileplaceholder.jpg" width="115" height="100" />
        <!--<i style="font-size: 5rem; align-self: center;" class="pi pi-users mx-auto"></i>-->
      </div>
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-5 chat-window">
        <div class="ui-g">
          <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">Autor: {{car?.autor}}</div>
          <h2 class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6 ml-2">Evento: {{car?.evento}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="loadingItem">
    <div class="ui-g car-item empty-car-item">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
        <div class="empty-car-item-index"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
        <div class="empty-car-item-image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8">
        <div class="ui-g">
          <div class="ui-g-12"><div class="empty-car-item-text"></div></div>
          <div class="ui-g-12"><div class="empty-car-item-text"></div></div>
          <div class="ui-g-12"><div class="empty-car-item-text"></div></div>
          <div class="ui-g-12"><div class="empty-car-item-text"></div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-virtualScroller>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using nested flexboxes. I've explained how those work with Angular in [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703997/how-to-use-nested-flexboxes-with-angular-components). Applying that solution to this problem involves applying the equivalent of the `flexbox-middle` class to each element that composes the virtual scrolling area:

```css
p-virtualScroller, 
/deep/ .ui-virtualscroller, 
/deep/ .ui-virtualscroller-content, 
/deep/ .ui-virtualscroller-list, 
/deep/ cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  display        : flex;
  flex           : 1;
  flex-direction : column;
}
```

With that styling, the `scrollHeight` attribute of the `p-virtualScroller` element should no longer be set as the component will flex to the height of the parent element:

```html
<p-virtualScroller [itemSize]="50" [value]="items">
  <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-obj>
    {{ obj.name }}
  </ng-template>
</p-virtualScroller>
```

The full code and a demo of the working result is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sygkjt).

Answer (score 1):

As of primeNg version: **16.0.0-rc.1**, there are a few changes to the accepted answer by *sawprogramming*. I've updated the accepted answer to utilize a new scss class.

---

component.scss

```scss
  .full-height-scroller{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .p-virtualscroller, .p-virtualscroller-content, p-scroller, .p-virtualscroller-list{
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```

component.html (ignoring virtualScroller configuration)

```html
  <p-virtualScroller ... class="full-height-scroller">
  </p-virtualScroller>
```

component.ts (make sure to use ViewEncapsulation.None so your class can reach the nested scroller components)

```
@Component({
  selector: ...
  templateUrl: ...
  styleUrls: ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Component {
}
```

---

**Keeping in mind**

- your parent container (holding the virtualScroller) needs to have the vertical space available.
- If you don't want to use ViewEncapsulation, you have to convert the scss class to use ng-deep or an equivalent.