# How to use nested flexboxes with Angular components?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I want to make all components added in through the router-outlet take up all of the available height and width of the page using flexboxes. Thanks to [ToolmakerSteve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58468476/4548231) to the "how to make nested flexboxes work", I know that it is possible to achieve the desired results using the following basic HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```html
<div id="flexbox-outer">
  <div id="flexbox-middle">
    <div id="flexbox-inner">    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
  height : 100%; 
  width  : 100%;
}
.flexbox-outer {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
}
.flexbox-middle {
  flex           : 1;
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
}
.flexbox-inner {
  flex: 1;
}
```

However, when I apply those classes to a basic Angular application, the `div` with the `flex-box-inner` class does not take up the entire height of the page as desired. Below is an example of the code that is not working (and a [stackblitz of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jszvi3)):

`index.html` and `app.component.html` (combined here):

```html
<html>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="flexbox-outer">
      <div class="flexbox-middle">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

`foo.component.html`:

```html
<div class="flexbox-inner">
  This should take up the entire width and height of the page.
</div>
```

How can I get the contents of the `foo.component.html` template to take up the entire height of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some inspection, I learned that components added through the `router-outlet` do not replace the `router-outlet`, but rather add their own hosting element at the same level of the `router-outlet`. So, the document structure that I thought was rendered like so:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="flexbox-outer">
      <div class="flexbox-middle">
        <!-- Removed, and replaced with contents of foo.component.html? -->
        <!--            <router-outlet></router-outlet>                 -->
        <div class="flexbox-inner">
          This should take up the entire width and height of the page.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Was actually rendered like this:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="flexbox-outer">
      <div class="flexbox-middle">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <foo>
          <div class="flexbox-inner">
            This should take up the entire width and height of the page.
          </div>
        </foo>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

So, to make this all work and have the contents of `foo.component.html` fill the height of the page, I just needed to add the `flexbox-middle` class to the host element of the `FooComponent` like so:

```
@Component({
  selector    : 'app-foo',
  templateUrl : './foo.component.html',
  host        : { 'class': 'flexbox-middle' }
})
export class FooComponent { }
```

The full code for the working result is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2ns61).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `css to app-foo` also for covering `height 100%`

```
app-foo{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```